# Am I exercising out too much?

Tags: exercise

So I am a 17 year old *fat* boy with a height of 5'9" and weigh around 183 pounds. I **can't** change my eating habits, I just love fast food and could't resist. So I decided to exercise as much as possible. Currently, per day, I cycle 14 klicks daily on a flat road and cycle around 7 klicks in the gym. I walk 4 klicks on a flat road and jog for around 1 klick on a treadmill. I spend around 10-12 minutes on an elliptical, burning about a hundred calories. Is this too much? I feel very tired sometimes. P.S: I **don't** lift weights.

Comment: It's easier to just not eat calories than burning them off. Having that said, many people jog/cycle to work as their commute much farther than you exercise every day. You can do it, but you need to build up endurance.

Comment: Here's a good [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UQbuzsY_34Q) to illustrate diet vs exercise.  You may want to reconsider your fast food.

Answer (score 1):

Apart from what @Boris and @Josaur said, I would like to suggest you some tips as you are only 17 years old.

1. Durability and quality of structure always depends on the raw materials that has been used for its construction. So, to start with **you can't just think about having a healthy body without following proper healthy diet**.
2. As you are just 17 years old and consuming cold drinks daily along with junks 2 times a week, its not good for your body in longer run. May be you wont feel the difference for next 7-8 years but gradually it'll take its toll.
3. For losing weight, this exercise in not that much sufficient given that you are having junks, chocolates and cold drinks so often. Reduce junks to once in a week at least along with cold drinks. Bro, you should watch out for the heavy amount of sugar that you are taking. It will surely hit your body hard and bad in long run inviting several diseases.
4. There are 2 things because of which you might be feeling tired:

   - You are not taking taking proper rest (7-8 hrs is a must if you are involved in physical exercises)
   - Your body is not getting proper energy from the food you are eating. You can't expect a bike to run on water , it needs petrol. Similarly you need to consume protein & carbs rich diet to fuel your body

So, give utmost respect to your body because **you can change everything but your body**

Answer (score 0):

So in total, you cycle/run 22km, plus 12 minutes on the elliptical (5km I guess).

Is it too much? That depends on what your goals are.

- If you want to lose fat, that's not enough, given that you eat junk food (every day?). And you don't tell much about the intensity of your training, which also plays a role in that. As said by @cbll, the first step to lose weight is your diet. Unless you train like an athlete several hours per day (more than 5 hours), don't expect to burn more calories than your fast food provides
- If you just want to do cardio, it might be a bit too much, because you don't give your body enough rest, that's why you feel tired. But it is also linked to your diet : if you don't eat well, you won't rest well. Your body needs good "fuel" to perform.

Comment: Umm.. No, actually, I dont eat junk food everyday, it's more like once every three days..

Comment: Eat chocolates and drink cold drinks everyday, though..

Answer (score 0):

**Are you exercising too much?** If you have no rest day in your week then yes. Otherwise, no (assuming you are getting 7-8 hours of sleep a night).

**Is your diet making you tired?** Yes, lots of junk food is not providing your body with fuel it needs to recover, eventually you will just be tired and fat.